# Including user:pass for elasticsearch upload in python script

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm having trouble including my username and password when I issue a PUT method to my elasticsearch server. The script reads my csv file and uploads the contents to ES. It works fine without issuing a username and password but I can't seem to find a way to include it in the httplib.HTTPConnection()

```
#url  = "10.100.1.16:9200"
key = "--user elastic:changeme"
url  = "10.100.9.21:9200"
path = "/" + args.elastic_path.strip("/")

print("Starting")
print(" CSV to ES ")
print("Importing %s rows into `%s` from '%s'" %(args.max_rows,args.elastic_path.strip("/"),args.csv_file))
print("")

count = 0
headers = []
with open(args.csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        if count == 0:
            for col in row:
                headers.append(col)
        elif count >= args.max_rows:
            exit('Max rows imported - exit')
        else:
            pos = 0
            _data = args.json_struct.replace("'",'"')
            _path = path
            for header in headers:
                _path = _path.replace('%'+header+'%',row[pos])
                _data = _data.replace('%'+header+'%',row[pos])
                pos += 1
            # Send the request
            connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
            connection.request('PUT', _path, _data)
            response = connection.getresponse()
            print response.status, response.reason
            data = response.read()
            print data

        count += 1

exit('End')
```

I need to include

> --user elastic:changeme

I was able to accomplish this with pyelasticsearch but I can't seem to move on without correctly this program

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a remark on your question: please add python version and libraries. Also, please remove unneeded stuff. 
Also, since you are using Security / Shield, I am a bit surprised that you don't use https. 
And you may want to consider using the requests library.
But this should be an answer, so here it comes. Include username and password in the headers like so:

```
import httplib
from base64 import b64encode
url  = "127.0.0.1:9200"
userAndPass = b64encode("elastic:changeme")
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  userAndPass } 
connection.request('GET','/',headers=headers)
resp = connection.getresponse()
print resp.status, resp.reason
```

200 OK

```
resp.read()
```

'{\n  "name" : "3paqSdV",\n  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",\n  "cluster_uuid" : "5MJosdgv-V7I6vIFb7AA",\n  "version" : {\n    "number" : "5.6.0",\n    "build_hash" : "781a835",\n    "build_date" : "2017-09-07T03:09:58.087Z",\n    "build_snapshot" : false,\n    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"\n  },\n  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"\n}\n'